# Choosing Filesystem

Tags: filesystems, ubuntu-16.04, veracrypt

When I create a standard VeraCrypt container on Ubuntu 16.04, I am given a choice of which filesystem to use.

But when I create a VeraCrypt container with both a standard and hidden partition, I am only given a choice of which filesystem to use *only on the hidden one*.

**How can I change the filesystem for the non-hidden one?**
(aside from using the hidden one as primary and non-hidden as secondary)

I have tried re-formatting the non-hidden partition using gnome-disks, but then the hidden partition will no longer be accessible (even using quick format).
After restoring the header (backed-up before formatting), the non-hidden partition sill does not work.

Comment: Afaik the problem with the non hidden filesystem is that some filesystems cannot be used or must be tuned to not write all over the place (destroying your hidden container)

Comment: The non-hidden partition cannot be restricted because that would tell an observer that there is something reserved. For this reason a hidden volume needs tomdepend on the fact that the primary filesystem is not very much used and naturally aligns all data usage at the front. Some filesystems have allocation groups tomspread out the files, and that's what damages the hidden volumes even with small number of (fake) files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The outer (non-hidden) volume cannot be restricted when an observer is present, because that would tell her that there is something reserved.

For this reason a hidden volume needs to depend on the fact that the primary filesystem is not very much used and naturally aligns all data usage to the front (and you never fill it).

Some filesystems have allocation groups to spread out the data blocks equally (which helps against fragmentation), and that's what damages the hidden volumes even with small number of (fake) files.

It is important to mount the inner volume so it can be protected. This interacts with the filesystem of the outer volume, so I guess this is why the type is restricted, see: https://veracrypt.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Protection%20of%20Hidden%20Volumes
If that protection is in place must mkfs/format activities would fail (and if not in place then damage the inner volume).